# php what happens using ->

Tags: php, codeigniter, object

In this statement from codeigniter

```
$this->db->select('')
```

Are we saying,

From the current model object, find the object called 'db' then run the function in 'db' called select?

Thanks

Comment: [Object Oriented Programming](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

`$this` is a reference to the current object.
`db` is a property of whichever object `$this` represents.
`select()` is a method of the `db` object.

You use `->` in an object oriented context to access methods and properties of an object.

**Edit**
To answer your question in the comments, we need to clarify the terminology being used.
A class has `methods` (functions) and `properties` (variables).

In this case, `db` is an object (you can tell because it has a `select` method). But in the context of the object represented by `$this`, it is a `property` of the object.

Comment: so am i right in thinking db is an object of the $this object. I understand $this->myMethod(); calls a method inside the object by theres a 3rd level here  - $this->db->select('') -

Answer (score 0):

`$this->db->select('mytable')`

would result in the follwing MySQL query:

```
'SELECT * FROM mytable'
```

[Here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html) is a link to the Active Record docs for CodeIgniter.